5 wires for ceiling light?
I removed an old fluorescent bulb fixture to replace it with an LED fixture.
I have 5 wires coming out of the ceiling.  I can tell which is the ground. Of the remaining 4, 1 is black, 1 is white and the other two are just covered in black tape.
How do I tell which of the two mystery wires goes with the white from the ceiling and white from new LED fixture versus which mystery wire goes with the black from the ceiling and black from the new LED fixture? This was how it was wired (3 wires in each wire connector) when I removed the old fixture and I failed to note which mystery wire goes with black and which with white.
Thank you!

One of those wires has damaged insulation and needs more tape,  it's not the black one with white paint on it,

Is this in a bathroom? Could this at one point have been a multifunction bathroom fan, such as the kind with a heater, a fan, a light, etc?

My attic has some old knob and tube wiring with separate runs for hot and neutral wires. I don't know why it was done this way, but as I traced the runs I noticed they would make pass through connections in receptacles out of order. For instance, circuit 8 runs the hot wire to the hallway light and then to the bedroom light where it terminates, but it runs the neutral wire to the bedroom light and then to the hallway light where it terminates.


This was how it was wired (3 wires in each wire connector)

According to that pattern at the light fixture
Two wires are the switched power for the lamp, the other two carry the switched power to the next lamp.
You've got two options, either guess and measure, or measure first.
Switched hot can be found using a non-contact voltage sensor,
Neutral will be the wire paired with it,
the identity of the taped wires (if they are not switched hot and neutral) will be harder to determine.
Easiest is probably to leave them temporarily unconnected so you can determin which fixture(s) they go to and then guess and measure to see if live comes out on the right terminal.
once you have identified which mystery wire should be neutral cover all the black tape on it with white tape or white sleeving.

Thanks Jasen, Mark and Jack.  Really cool to be able to ask a question like this.
That being said: I'm calling an electrician! :)

You're going to need a volt meter to find out which wires are your neutral and your always hot. The other two wires will probably go to your switch. Confirm that by testing continuity between the switch wires and those two. If all checks out, your neutral would get connected to the white wire from the new light. Your always hot wire would get connected to one of the switch wires and the other switch wire would get connected to the black wire fron your new light. Verify you have a ground and connect it to your new light if it has a ground connection.
Now the bad news. Those wires are a fire waiting to happen. I'm guessing the taped wires are taped because the insulation has crumbled off the wires. On the black fabric wire, you can actually see the bare wire sticking through the insulation. The white fabric wire also has insulation damage.  There also appears to be a red wire burnt where the two taped wires exit the pancake box. This really needs to get checked out by someone who know what they are doing before any new light are installed.

always hot not present there, read the last paragraph in the question.

"red" could be a funnel end (whatever they are correctly called) on the end of the conduit (or BX or however this wiring is installed)

@Jasen  And you are going to take their word for it?  Better to test everything.

A detail was given and you have decided to ignore it, and go with a made-up scenario as the most likely solution you should at minimum explain why you have decided to ignore that part of the question.

Is there a wall switch for this light?  If so, you probably have a switch loop.  Power (hot and neutral) come into the ceiling box.  Instead of connecting to the light fixture, the hot connects to a wire running down to the switch.  Another wire runs from the switch back up to the ceiling box - this is a switched hot, which is hot only when the switch is turned on.  The light fixture is connected to the switched hot and the neutral.
You'll need a way to check for voltage on the wires.  Only one of them will be hot compared to both ground and neutral - that's the incoming hot.  In looking at the picture it looks like there are two cloth covered wires coming in through one cable - one is black and the other is sort of white.  Those are probably the incoming power.
The other two tape covered wires are probably the wires to and from the switch.  With all power off, you can check this by measuring continuity between those two wires with the switch on and off.  There should be continuity with the switch on, and not with the switch off.
If that checks out, connect the incoming hot to one of the switch loop wires, and connect the other switch loop wire to the light fixture along with the neutral and ground.

no switch loop, read the last paragraph in the question.
